# Adding a Kinect to my Gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I have a URDF model that is working in gazebo that i copied from the book *Programming Robots with ROS*. I would like to add a Kinect sensor to this model so i can simulate my robot but i cant for the life of me figure out how do this. Most resources that i found are like [this example.](https://answers.ros.org/question/110151/kinect-urdf/) which says that i should use the model found in the turtlebot_description folder but i am unsure what files i need and how exactly to import them into my URDF. I found [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_depth_camera&cat=connect_ros) which edits the kinect model found in the gazebo models folder, and this worked perfectly so i know its possible.
I think what i need is for someone to really spell it out for me what i need to add to my urdf and my launch file to add a kinect.

Here is my URDF I would like to replace the hokuyo_link with a Kinect:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="tortoisebot">
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver">
                <color rgba="0.75 0.75 0.75 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1.0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.015" iyy="0.0375" izz="0.0375" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <link name="front_caster">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.00083" iyy="0.00083" izz="0.000167" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    <joint name="front_caster_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="front_caster" />
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.3 0 0" />
    </joint>
    
    <link name="front_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black" />
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>


    <joint name="front_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="front_caster"/>
        <child link="front_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="0.05 0 -0.15"/>
    </joint>

        <link name="right_wheel">
                <visual>
                        <geometry>
                                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
                        </geometry>
                        <material name="black" />
                </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </link>
        <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
                <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
                <parent link="base_link"/>
                <child link="right_wheel"/>
                <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 -0.125 -0.15"/>
        </joint>


        <link name="left_wheel">
                <visual>
                        <geometry>
                                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
                        </geometry>
                        <material name="black" />
                </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </link>
        <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
                <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
                <parent link="base_link"/>
                <child link="left_wheel"/>
                <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 0.125 -0.15"/>
        </joint>



    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
            <leftJoint>left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
            <wheelSeparation>0.25</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.07</wheelDiameter>
            <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
            <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="joint_state_publisher" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
            <jointName>front_caster_joint, front_wheel_joint</jointName>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <link name="hokuyo_link">
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1e-5" />
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="hokuyo_joint" type="fixed">
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.2" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="hokuyo_link"/>
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link">
        <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <update_rate>40</update_rate>
            <ray>
                <scan>
                    <horizontal>
                        <samples>720</samples>
                        <resolution>1</resolution>
                        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
                    </horizontal>
                </scan>
                <range>
                    <min>0.10</min>
                    <max>30.0</max>
                    <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                </range>
            </ray>
            <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
                <topicName>/scan</topicName>
                <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
            </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>


</robot>
```

**UPDATE:**
After implementing the code in the answer below i get the following code. unfortionately now i have an issue where the kinect plugin is working but everything is shown as being above the robot and rotated to the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="tortoisebot">

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver">
        <color rgba="0.75 0.75 0.75 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.015" iyy="0.0375" izz="0.0375" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <link name="front_caster">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00083" iyy="0.00083" izz="0.000167" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="front_caster_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_caster"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.3 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="front_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="front_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="front_caster"/>
    <child link="front_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="0.05 0 -.15"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="right_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 -0.125 -.15"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="left_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 0.125 -.15"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="hokuyo_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="hokuyo_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.2" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="hokuyo_link"/>
  </joint>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <leftJoint>right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
      <wheelSeparation>0.25</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.07</wheelDiameter>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="joint_state_publisher" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
      <jointName>front_caster_joint, front_wheel_joint</jointName>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link">
        <sensor name="hokuyo" type="depth">
            <!-- openni plugin has the x pointing towards the scene, so rotate to have z -->
            <pose frame="hokuyo_link">0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -1.5708 1.5708</pose>
        <!--origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/-->
            <camera>
                <horizontal_fov>0.74839718</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <width>1280</width>
                    <height>1024</height>
                    <format>L_INT8</format>
                </image>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.1</near>
                    <far>10.0</far>
                </clip>
                <noise>
                    <type>gaussian</type>
                    <mean>0.5</mean>
                    <stddev>1.0</stddev>
                </noise>
            </camera>
            <plugin name="kinect_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
                <baseline>0.1</baseline>
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
                will control the frame rate. -->
                <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
                <cameraName>hokuyo</cameraName>
                <imageTopicName>/3d_image/image_raw</imageTopicName>
                <cameraInfoTopicName>/3d_image/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
                <depthImageTopicName>/3d_image/image_raw_depth</depthImageTopicName>
                <depthImageInfoTopicName>/3d_image/camera_info</depthImageInfoTopicName>
                <pointCloudTopicName>/3d_image/3d_cloud</pointCloudTopicName>
                <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
                <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
                <pointCloudCutoffMax>2.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
            </plugin>
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328937/adding-a-kinect-to-my-gazebo-simulation/) by [logan.ydid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41911/logan.ydid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not quite sure if I am missing something, but seeing for the moment nobody is responding i will try to help.

I think you should add the sensor more or less like that:

> ```
> <gazebo reference="world">
> ```

```
    <sensor name="world" type="depth">
        <!-- openni plugin has the x pointing towards the scene, so rotate to have z -->
        <pose frame="world">0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 -1.5708 1.5708</pose>
        <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>0.74839718</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
                <width>1280</width>
                <height>1024</height>
                <format>L_INT8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
                <near>0.1</near>
                <far>10.0</far>
            </clip>
            <noise>
                <type>gaussian</type>
                <mean>0.5</mean>
                <stddev>1.0</stddev>
            </noise>
        </camera>
        <plugin name="kinect_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
            <baseline>0.1</baseline>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
            will control the frame rate. -->
            <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
            <cameraName>kinect_test</cameraName>
            <imageTopicName>/3d_image/image_raw</imageTopicName>
            <cameraInfoTopicName>/3d_image/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
            <depthImageTopicName>/3d_image/image_raw_depth</depthImageTopicName>
            <depthImageInfoTopicName>/3d_image/camera_info</depthImageInfoTopicName>
            <pointCloudTopicName>/3d_image/3d_cloud</pointCloudTopicName>
            <frameName>kinect_body</frameName>
            <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
            <pointCloudCutoffMax>2.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
        </plugin>
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>1.0</update_rate>
    </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

Hope at least gives you more clues from where to follow!

---

Originally posted by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) with karma: 187 on 2019-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logan.ydid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41911/logan.ydid/) on 2019-07-22**:
Yay! Thank you this works! Now I'm just having trouble with the orientation of the sensor. In gazebo if I place something in front of the robot it appears above the robot rotated 90 degrees about the z access. I've tried adjusting the pose tag after the first comment in your code but it didn't seem to make a difference. I've also tried changing the orientation in the joint definition but that just changes the orientation of the sensor in gazebo but not in rviz. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2019-07-23**:
Maybe my error adding as a main frame "world". Can you try to add as a main frame a link instead of a joint? I have checked my code and i have that.

Anyway I am not quite sure that this is the solution, but lets try xD

**Comment by [logan.ydid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41911/logan.ydid/) on 2019-07-24**:
Haha I thought that seemed weird . So do you mean to do something like this?`<pose frame="link_name">0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 -1.5708 1.5708</pose>`

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2019-07-24**:
Yes! That's what I wanted to say! Any news?

**Comment by [logan.ydid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41911/logan.ydid/) on 2019-07-24**:
Hmmm unfortunately i still have been unable to get it to work. i have tried changing the link name to `hokuyo_link` just like my laser scanner from before and to `base_link` but to no avail. i have also tried changing the name of the camera in the plugin to match the sensor name but that didnt change anything either. when i look at the camera view from rviz it looks like everything is in the correct orientation but the point cloud still shows up above the robot. If it helps i put the urdf i am currently using as an update to my post. thank you so much for your help!

**Comment by [logan.ydid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41911/logan.ydid/) on 2019-07-27**:
@Solrac3589 Thank you for your help, you've been immensely helpful! I've decided to start another question about orientation in Rviz. it can be found here: https://answers.ros.org/question/329409/point-cloud-in-wrong-position-relative-to-robot/